# How to Run a workflow on an item inserted by an anonymous user

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

Is there a way to start a sharepoint designer workflow on an item inserted by an anonymous user on an internet-facing Sharepoint publishing site.
As far as i understand, as of the infrastructure updates, workflows cannot be started on new items inserted by an anonymous user or a system admin.
We are using Moss 2007 with SP2.

What we need to do is a feedback list that sends an email on the event of a new item inserted to the list by an anonymous user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this doesn't help if your stuck with designer but you can have an ItemAdded event that contains a bit of code which starts the workflow itself. Or which may be more applicable, sending the email directly from the ItemAdded event. Workflow is best used for long processes that involve user interaction.

Comment: But still with an event handler i need to insert the item by impersonating a user (other than the system admin), Right?

Comment: Anon users have particular permissions associated with them. If you give them contribue permissions where they are able to create list items, then they also should have permissions to start workflows. The ItemAdded event should also be able to start it under the same Anon permissions.

I always run as a system admin while developing and testing and my workflows always start when a list item is created. I've run before and after infrastructure updates and I've never had the problem your describing.